# Getting List of child terms from custom taxonomy parent

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I am attempting to create section of my website footer that has link li of terms from a parent for a custom taxonomy I created.

```
function add_custom_taxonomies() {
  // Add new "producttype" taxonomy to products
  register_taxonomy('producttype', 'product', array(
    // Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
    'hierarchical' => true,
    // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => _x( 'Producttypes', 'taxonomy general name' ),
      'singular_name' => _x( 'Producttype', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
      'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Producttypes' ),
      'all_items' => __( 'All Producttypes' ),
      'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Producttype' ),
      'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Producttype:' ),
      'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Producttype' ),
      'update_item' => __( 'Update Producttype' ),
      'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Producttype' ),
      'new_item_name' => __( 'New Producttype Name' ),
      'menu_name' => __( 'Product Type' ),
    ),
    // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
    'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'Producttype', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
      'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/locations/"
      'hierarchical' => true // This will allow URL's like "/locations/boston/cambridge/"
    ),
  ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_taxonomies', 0 );
```

I have a parent that i created for the taxonomy "producttype" called "Type" I would like to get only those child terms under the parent term "Type" and display them as a link. I created the parent term in the wordpress dashboard manually.

Answer (score 1):

[`get_term_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) should be able to do just that. The example in the link looks good.

Comment: Hello @Taruckus thank you for your reply, I have attempter to use the get_ter_children() like so `<?php 

$terms= get_term_children( 'Type', 'producttype' );


echo $terms;


?>` but it does seem to be working any idea why? thank you.

Comment: @steamfunk The first argument needs to be the term ID, not the name or slug.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic the 'Type' is the Term iD i need the children of to be displayed. I created the parent in my dashboard manually. and the 'Producttype' is the custom taxonomy i created for a custom post type called 'product'

Comment: So wait, that was just an example? Or are you actually using `'Type`' as the first argument?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic yes "Type" is what i have named the parent term. This is a parent term in my custom taxonomy named producttype in which i have "Type" & "Company" as parent terms with a bunch of children.

Comment: Yes, so you need to use the ID, not the name.

Comment: I was out for the wknd. Does TheDeadMedic's suggestion make sense? You can find the term ID for a given term in the backend, or let me know if you need something a little more dynamic, like the term ID of the current page.

Comment: Where would i find the ID for the parent term? I made the terms through the dashboard?

Comment: One way to find it is to go to the term's edit page and look at the url:
http://example.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=pcategories&tag_ID=8&post_type=series

the "tag_ID" is what you're looking for, so in that example, it's 8.